# Scrolling doesn't work in Terminal for commands like less

Tags: terminal, bash, macos, zsh

I used to be able to scroll using the trackpad through git diff or man pages which both use less when the output doesn't fit on screen. Today I restarted my computer and that behaviour is gone and I can no longer scroll down and if I scroll up it scrolls the terminal scrollbar showing previous commands. However in vim scrolling still works as expected.

The first thing I checked is the "Scroll alternate screen" Terminal setting and it is checked as expected. I also tried with iTerm2 and have the same issue even with the "Scroll wheel sends arrow keys when in alternate screen mode" setting enabled.

My default shell is zsh so I tried with bash and then sh. Both have the same behaviour and I can't scroll through the output.

Because scrolling still works with some commands like vim it seems like the issue might be that less is no longer recognized as an "alternate screen" but I have no idea why. Updating to the latest less version available on brew did not help.

Comment: Same issue here. I have checked everything, it just doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Almost certain this is the issue: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/pull/6611

Comment: I was using zprezto and had to change the less settings according to this line: https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/blob/7c94154dda2dfcf02515f1caf1e9dfe6d80b0350/runcoms/zprofile#L55

Comment: I know this is old and OP explicitly tried this, but as of February, 2020, i have to toggle "Scroll alternate screen" every time I restart my computer. Terminal -> Preferences -> "Profiles" Tab -> "Keyboard" tab -> toggle off/on "Scroll alternate screen". For anyone encountering this currently.

Answer (score 8):

it is weird, I had the exact issue this morning with iterm2.

I ended up adding the following to my `~/.zshrc`:

```
export LESS=-R
```

**Important:** you might want to take a look at the flags you are using before running this command and understanding what each of them do.

Sources I looked at to arrive to this conclusion:

1. https://askubuntu.com/questions/803486/can-i-scroll-to-new-lines-using-mouse-wheel-inside-git-diff
2. https://superuser.com/questions/455212/how-to-make-mouse-wheel-scroll-the-less-pager-using-bash-and-gnome-terminal

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: `echo $LESS` returns `-FRX` at the moment for me. Looks like the `-X` might be the issue.

Comment: I tried removing X as well, didn't fix it for me. I also had the same flags enabled.

Comment: Adding `export LESS=-FR` to my `.zshrc` fixed it for me. In iTerm do you have the "Scroll wheel sends arrow keys when in alternate screen mode" setting set to Yes?

Comment: That is correct. "Scroll wheel sends arrow keys when in alternate screen mode" is on.

Comment: Thanks Crhis911, that was the setting causing problems in my zsh

Comment: I also had `export PAGER='less -SFX'` and removing the `-X` flag got the scrolling to work in iterm2 again.  I agree with @Chris911, looks like the `-X` is the culprit here.  But of course, now without the `-X` certain commands like `git branch`  show no output. :rolling_eyes

Comment: I had the opposite. On OS X 10.14.6 for me, if I have "-r" (or equivalently "-R"), it doesn't display multi-page files correctly. If I take it off, it does. C'est la vie.